# How to disable scaling Linear Layout when keyboard is up

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I am a begginer in android api and I want not to scale my Linear Layout when keyboard is up. Just like it is in scroll view. Is this possible to do it in xml?
Thanks for any help;-)

Edit:
Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_home"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:weightSum="7"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/login_label"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:background="@drawable/input"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:background="@drawable/input"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/reminder"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/register_button"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/go"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/right"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can only choose to accept one answer (accepting Henshaw's took it away from mine). But you can upvote several.

Comment: I want to, but I have not enough reputation to do this ;-( (12 but requires 15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

"adjustResize"

The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

"adjustPan"

The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" or android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your Activity inside your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) but it applies to whole `Activity`. There's no way to control separate `ViewGroup` in similar way.

> How the main window of the activity interacts with the window
>   containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The setting for this attribute
>   affects two things: The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is
>   hidden or visible - when the activity becomes the focus of user
>   attention. The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether
>   it is resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether
>   its  contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the
>   window is covered by the soft keyboard.